# How to have un-tracked weights in custom keras layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to create a custom keras layer (a codebook for a VQVAE model.)  While training I would like to have a `tf.Variable` which tracks the usage of each code so I can restart unused codes.  So I created my Codebook layer as follows...

```
class Codebook(layers.Layer): 
     def __init__(self, num_codes, code_reset_limit = None, **kwargs): 
         super().__init__(**kwargs) 
         self.num_codes = num_codes 
         self.code_reset_limit = code_reset_limit 
         if self.code_reset_limit: 
             self.code_counter = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_codes, dtype = tf.int32), trainable = False) 
     def build(self, input_shape): 
         self.codes = self.add_weight(name = 'codes',  
                                      shape = (self.num_codes, input_shape[-1]), 
                                      initializer = 'random_uniform',  
                                      trainable = True) 
         super().build(input_shape)
```

The issue I have is that the `Layer` class finds the member variable `self.code_counter` and adds it to the list of weights which are saved with the layer.  It also expects the `self.code_counter` to be present when weights are loaded which is not the case when I run in inference mode.  How can I make it so keras does not track a variable in my layer.  I do not want it persisted or to be part of the `layers.weights`.